# Simple and two head arrows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a simple arrow and a two head arrow. I used the following to make a simple arrow, but I doubt this is the easiest method :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
arr_width = .009   #  I don't know what unit it is here.
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(range(10))
ax1.arrow(1, 1, 0, .5, width = arr_width, head_width = 3 * arr_width, 
          head_length = 9 * arr_width)
plt.show()
```

I can't find how to make two head arrows with this method.

Comment: The code you've supplied doesn't work.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can create a double-headed arrow using the [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) method with blank text annotation and setting the `arrowprops` dict to include `arrowstyle='<->'` as shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.annotate(s='', xy=(1,1), xytext=(0,0), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->'))

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: This solution provides an arrow slightly shorter than desired. Moreover, using arrowstyle = '<->' means than one cannot use shrink = 0.0 in annotate. I therefore consider this question still open.

Comment: @newling You can use`plt.annotate(s='', xy=(1,1), xytext=(0,0), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->', shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0))` instead

Comment: On matplotlib==3.0.0 I had to change `s=''` to `text=''`.

Answer (score 16):

You can create double-headed arrows by plotting two `plt.arrow` which are overlapping. The code below helps to do that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

# red arrow
plt.arrow(0.15, 0.5, 0.75, 0, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.03, linewidth=4, color='r', length_includes_head=True)

# green arrow
plt.arrow(0.85, 0.5, -0.70, 0, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.03, linewidth=4, color='g', length_includes_head=True)

plt.show()
```

And the result is like this:

[image: Double-Headed Arrow]

You can see that the red arrow is being plotted firstly, and then the green one. When you supply the correct coordinates, it looks like a double-headed.

Comment: This approach has the downside that the rectangular start of one arrow shows outside the end of the other. It can be seen slightly in this image, a few red pixels on the left side, and the effect can become very visible depending on arrow widths. In `FancyArrowPatch`, it could be mitigated with `shrinkA=head_length`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html) to draw a two-headed arrow. This class allows to specify [`arrowstyle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html):

```py
import matplotlib.patches as patches

p1 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (1, 1), arrowstyle='<->', mutation_scale=20)
p2 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((1, 0), (0, 1), arrowstyle='<|-|>', mutation_scale=20)
```

This produces the following arrows:

[image: Arrows]

Comment: This is the backend of `plt.annotate` BTW: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.3.2/lib/matplotlib/text.py#L1739 but feels cleaner since no dummy empty message `s=''`. I only had one problem with this (and `plt.annotate`): increasing `linewidth` makes the pointer head rounded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545470/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-between-the-tip-of-the-arrow-of-a-fancyarrowpatch-a/64545471#64545471

Comment: To add a `FancyArrowPatch` to a specific axis, use `ax.add_patch(p1)`. Also consider using `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` to avoid an offset to the coordinates specified

Answer (score 2):

You can draw two one-headed arrows along the same line but in opposite directions.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Arrows
plt.arrow(0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, color='red', head_length = 0.07, head_width = 0.025, length_includes_head = True)
plt.arrow(0.7, 0.8, -0.4, -0.7, color='red', head_length = 0.07, head_width = 0.025, length_includes_head = True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to provide code with your solutions (if possible of course).

Comment: Edit your answer and add this solution with correct code formatting. And welcome to StackOverflow, thanks for contributing.