# Matplotlib connect scatterplot points with double headed arrow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have scatter plot like below:

[image]

I want to connect all blue points with the red point with a double headed arrow.

below is the code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(lon, lat, c='blue', alpha=0.7, s=size, label='Local Hub')
ax1.scatter(121.222824, 28.901852, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=120, label='Gateway Hub Hub')
# plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you post some example data and corresponding plotting code?

Comment: Use a for loop of points and use annotate to connect them like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761717/matplotlib-simple-and-two-head-arrows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib simple and two head arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761717/matplotlib-simple-and-two-head-arrows)